# get specific colunm from latest five record in the MySQL DB

Tags: php, mysqli

I have following code.This code doesn't show any result. Please explain what is the issue?

```
<?php
require_once("connnection.php"); 

$con=mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();

}

?>
<div style="position:absolute;top:200px;right:65px; padding:10px; background-color:#CCFFFF; width:300px; height:400px;">
<hr>
<p><strong>Latest posts</strong></p>
<hr style="position:relative; top:40px; left:30px; width:80%; ">
<?php
$sql = "SELECT question FROM comment ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5";
if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {

    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
        printf("%s\n", $row[3]);
    }

    /* free result set */

}
?>
```

I want to get five latest questions from the db and display it.DB has five records. Table comment has 4 fields. "question" is the last field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$row[3]` is undefined. You need to use `$row[0]`

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
    printf( "%s\n", $row[0] );
}
```

Alternatively:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { // notice the use of `fetch_assoc`
    echo $row['question'] . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks!It worked! but as a single line, new line character isn't working .Can you solve it too :)

Comment: @cmit You probably want the HTML tag for that: `<br />`

Answer (score 1):

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
    printf("%s\n", $row[3]);
}
```

You're selecting only the `questions` field but somehow enumerating the third field. You have an option to use mysqli_fetch_assoc as the following to avoid any confusion in the future

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    printf("%s\n", $row['questions']);
}
```

Or you can use `$row[0]` instead of `$row['3']`

Answer (score 1):

You can use echo $row['question'] is the column name for questions is "question" else find the column index starting from 0 and asign the value as  $row[0] (example 0)

```
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
          echo $row['question']."<br>";
       }
```

it's recommended that you should use column name because, if in future you change the table structure, your code will not get affected by changes